# Linking TFS work items to Zendesk tickets

Tags: team-foundation-server

we're trying to integrate TFS with Zendesk.

TFS has a built in interface for updating Zendesk tickets when a work item is commented on. It  can be defined with Service Hooks.
[image]
The Service Hook successfully connected to my Zendesk account, but we don't know how to link work items to tickets.

I couldn't find any documentation from either project.

Any information will be appreciated!

**UPDATE**: I am aware of the available VSTS integration, but we have on-premesis - which is not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

There is documentation for VSTS: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/service-hooks/services/zendesk?view=vsts

It may be similar for TFS.